# Handling Database Triggers in GoSQL

Tags: mysql, go

I'm currently learning to use the Go sql drivers (with MySQL) to talk to a database, and I want to insert a trigger that will be activated when a new record is inserted into a table.

I know that to do this in pure SQL, the statement needs to look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON table_1 
FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + new.amount
```

but I'm not sure what this returns, so don't know how to structure as a go/sql query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creating the trigger was successful you'll get `nil` as the second return value from [db.Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) if, on the other hand, the query failed you'll get an error with details for why.

For example:

```
_, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON table_1 FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + new.amount`)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
// Output: none
```

Let's say you run the same query a second time

```
_, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON table_1 FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + new.amount`)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
// Output: Error 1359: Trigger already exists
```

Or let's say you mistype the table name

```
_, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON table_987 FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + new.amount`)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
// Output: Error 1146: Table 'dbname.table_987' doesn't exist
```